# Select data from database when i click the submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a table when i want to click a button it get data from database to table i try this code but i get error.

```
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title">
                        <h5>Conference Table</h5>
                        <div class="ibox-tools">
                            <a class="collapse-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="table_data_tables.php#">
                                <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                                <li><a href="table_data_tables.php#">Config option 1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="table_data_tables.php#">Config option 2</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <a class="close-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="ibox-content">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-5">
                                        <button class="btn btn-white" type="submit">Cancel</button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Run Report</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>No</th>
                                    <th>Aim</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>Funded</th>
                                    <th>Male</th>
                                    <th>Female</th>
                                    <th>Disabled</th>
                                    <th>Total</th>
                                    <th>Comments</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'user2', 'password', 'database' );


if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
} 

           if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $query = 'SELECT * FROM conference';
                $data = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) ;

                if (!$data) {
                    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
                } else {

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
                        echo "<tr>
                            <td>" . $row['NOTW'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Aim'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Funded'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Male'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Female'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Disabled'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Total'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Comments'] . "</td>
                            <td>   Edit   Trush  </td>                                           
                          </tr>";
                     }
                 }
            }
                    ?>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

the Error is

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in /home/cshrnaf/public_html/MIS_CSHRN/reporttest.php on
>   line 265

265 line:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
```

**UPDATE**

After Change code to:

```
<div class="ibox-content">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>No</th>
                                    <th>Aim</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>Funded</th>
                                    <th>Male</th>
                                    <th>Female</th>
                                    <th>Disabled</th>
                                    <th>Total</th>
                                    <th>Comments</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'user2', 'password', 'database' );


if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
} 
/*
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    */
$query = 'SELECT * FROM conference';
$data = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);


                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) 
                    {
                        echo "  <tr>
                                    <td>" . $row['NOTW'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Aim'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Funded'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Male'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Female'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Disabled'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Total'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Comments'] . "</td>
                            <td>   Edit   Trush  </td>  

                                </tr>";
                    }
//}
                    ?>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

data will be loaded if the page will be loaded

Comment: Check for Errors after execute `mysql_query`

Comment: remove These line `?>
<?php`

Comment: @Jens Thanks for comment  : ) i remove those line still i got same error. i edit the code also you can see

Comment: But you check not for error after executing mysqli_query. But i think `isset($_POST['submit'])` returns false, so the query will never executed

Comment: @jens like, sorry i didnt got.

Comment: Read about mysqli_error

Comment: Check if there are results of your query before to use mysqli_fetch_array():

`if ($data):` [...] `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))` [...] `endif;`

Comment: The problem is that `$query` and `$data` are assigned only when you submit the form, i.e. when you load the page initially, these two variables are undefined, but script continues anyway, so put `while` loop also in this `if` statement.

Comment: @NachoM. Thank you for you commment friend, i am new in php could you please write complete check error code, Thanks : )

Comment: Farhadpaikan , the user @Jens jotted down the solution you asked me for: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38344680/6250357)

Comment: Please, show us the html button code that performs the submit to a better understanding of the issue with the db connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `isset($_POST['submit'])` Returns false the query is never executed and $data is null. But the while Loop will be executed. So Change your code to:

```
           if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $query = 'SELECT * FROM conference';
                $data = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) ;

                if (!$data) {
                    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
                } else {

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
                        echo "<tr>
                            <td>" . $row['NOTW'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Aim'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Funded'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Male'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Female'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Disabled'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Total'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Comments'] . "</td>
                            <td>   Edit   Trush  </td>                                           
                          </tr>";
                     }
                 }
            }
```

**UPDATE**

in $_POST the Name is used. not the type, so Change:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Run Report</button>
```

to

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="Report">Run Report</button>
```

and

```
       if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

to

```
       if (isset($_POST['report'])) {
```

Comment: the above code works and i get the data when i open the page, but click button has no action, i want get data when i click the submit button

Comment: @Farhadpaikan That can not be. Maybe you refer to the wrong answer?

Comment: i edit the code you can see, it works but without submit click : )

Comment: @Farhadpaikan refer to the answer of SumanDey as a comment to my answer

Comment: @Farhadpaikan also do not Change the question. Add changes as update at the end of the question. So everybody can see what the original question

Comment: @Farhadpaikan and there is no submit button shown in your code

Comment: Sorry O:-) , i try the code wrote but it doesnt give any result and nothing happened, even i dont get error message

Comment: @Farhadpaikan Because the `submit`is not set. Can you add the form with the button to your question please?

Comment: I did, take a look : )

Comment: Thanks a ton , i add name now it works like clock : )

Answer (score 0):

try this for connect database

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'mis_db' );
```

may be thats why you got a error

Answer (score 0):

Simply include `while` loop into `if` statement in order to be executed only when you submit the form:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM conference';
    $data = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
        echo "  <tr>
            <td>" . $row['NOTW'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Aim'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Funded'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Male'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Female'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Disabled'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Total'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Comments'] . "</td>
            <td>   Edit   Trush  </td>                                           
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: when? before or after submit?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing null value to the mysqli_fetch_array() function.because the value of $data variable can not be identified at the function.make

```
$data="" ;
```

at the beginning of the php code.

try this code

```
<div class="ibox-content">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Aim</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Funded</th>
                <th>Male</th>
                <th>Female</th>
                <th>Disabled</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Comments</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $data="";
                $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'mis_db');

                if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
                    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                        . mysqli_connect_error());
                }
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    $query = 'SELECT * FROM conference';
                    $data = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
                }

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
                    echo "  <tr>
                            <td>" . $row['NOTW'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Aim'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Funded'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Male'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Female'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Disabled'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Total'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Comments'] . "</td>
                            <td>   Edit   Trush  </td>                                           
                        </tr>";
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you showed us the "submit" button, the below code should work on '*Run Report*' button is pressed:

This is the complete solution to your question:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                <div class="ibox-title">
                    <h5>Conference Table</h5>
                    <div class="ibox-tools">
                        <a class="collapse-link">
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="table_data_tables.php#">
                            <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                            <li><a href="table_data_tables.php#">Config option 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="table_data_tables.php#">Config option 2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <a class="close-link">
                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-5">
                            <button class="btn btn-white" type="submit">Cancel</button>
                            <form action="" method="post">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Run Report</button><input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true"/>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>No</th>
                                <th>Aim</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Funded</th>
                                <th>Male</th>
                                <th>Female</th>
                                <th>Disabled</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Comments</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                            $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'cshrnaf_user2', '=cXlIBsdMkdr', 'cshrnaf_mis_db');


                            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                                if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
                                    echo mysqli_connect_error();
                                    exit();
                                }

                                $query = 'SELECT * FROM conference';
                                $data = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

                                if (!$data) {
                                    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
                                } else {

                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
                                        echo "<tr>
                                                    <td>" . $row['NOTW'] . "</td>
                                                    <td>" . $row['Aim'] . "</td>
                                                    <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
                                                    <td>" . $row['Funded'] . "</td>
                                                    <td>" . $row['Male'] . "</td>
                                                    <td>" . $row['Female'] . "</td>
                                                    <td>" . $row['Disabled'] . "</td>
                                                    <td>" . $row['Total'] . "</td>
                                                    <td>" . $row['Comments'] . "</td>
                                                    <td>   Edit   Trush  </td>                                           
                                              </tr>";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you called ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
using       ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data))

   this code i used to test for tou with dreamweaver ADOBE
        its work fine
    <?php require_once('Connections/test.php'); ?>
    <?php
    mysql_select_db($database_test, $test);
    $query_table = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
    $table = mysql_query($query_table, $test) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_table = mysql_fetch_assoc($table);
    $totalRows_table = mysql_num_rows($table);
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="200" border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <?php do { ?>
      <th scope="col"><?php echo $row_table['col1']; ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?php echo $row_table['col2']; ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?php echo $row_table['col3']; ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?php echo $row_table['col4']; ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?php echo $row_table['col5']; ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?php echo $row_table['col6']; ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?php echo $row_table['col7']; ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?php echo $row_table['col8']; ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?php echo $row_table['col9']; ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?php echo $row_table['col10']; ?></th></tr><br>
          <?php } while ($row_table = mysql_fetch_assoc($table)); ?>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    mysql_free_result($table);
    ?>
     //OUTPUT

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="200" border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">insert1col1</th>
            <th scope="col">insert1col2</th>
            <th scope="col">insert1col3</th>
            <th scope="col">insert1col4</th>
            <th scope="col">insert1col5</th>
            <th scope="col">insert1col6</th>
            <th scope="col">insert1col7</th>
            <th scope="col">insert1col8</th>
            <th scope="col">insert1col9</th>
            <th scope="col">insert1col10</th></tr><br>
            <th scope="col">insert2col1</th>
            <th scope="col">insert2col2</th>
            <th scope="col">insert2col3</th>
            <th scope="col">insert2col4</th>
            <th scope="col">insert2col5</th>
            <th scope="col">insert2col6</th>
            <th scope="col">insert2col7</th>
            <th scope="col">insert2col8</th>
            <th scope="col">insert2col9</th>
            <th scope="col">insert2col10</th></tr><br>
              </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this its work [Test link](http://cureesse.com/php/op.php)

```
<div class="ibox-content">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>No</th>
                                    <th>Aim</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>Funded</th>
                                    <th>Male</th>
                                    <th>Female</th>
                                    <th>Disabled</th>
                                    <th>Total</th>
                                    <th>Comments</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'mis_db');

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
} 
/*
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    */
$query = 'SELECT * FROM conference';
$data = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);


                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) 
                    {
                        echo "  <tr>
                                    <td>" . $row['NOTW'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Aim'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Funded'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Male'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Female'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Disabled'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Total'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['Comments'] . "</td>
                            <td>   Edit   Trush  </td>  

                                </tr>";
                    }
//}
                    ?>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: the above code works and i get the data when i open the page, but click button has no action, i want get data when i click the submit button